# Data truncation message when inserting data from one row to another row

Tags: c#, datarow

Is there a way to allow data to get truncated if its too long when inserting it from one
row to another row? Whats happening now is that it gets an error and doesn't add the row if one of the fields is too long.

Here is the piece of code that I have:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();  
for (int j = 0; j < edi50.Columns.Count; j++)  
    dr[j] = dr50[j];

dt.Rows.Add(dr);  

try  
{  
    RemoveNulls(dt);  
    daEDI40050.Update(dt);  
}  
catch (Exception e)  
{  
    string m = e.Message;  
}
```

I have a description field 25 chars long but the data is 34 chars going into it. I want to be able to have it insert the 25 and truncate the rest and still add the row.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the schema from database first(untested):

```
DataTable schema;
using (var con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    var getSchemaSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tableName);
    using (var schemaCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(getSchemaSql, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
        {
            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
    }
}
```

and then something similar to this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < schema.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    DataRow schemaRow = schema.Rows[j];
    Type dataType = schemaRow.Field<Type>("DataType");
    int columnSize = schemaRow.Field<int>("ColumnSize");
    if (dataType.FullName == "System.String")
    {
        String value = dr50[j] as String;
        if (value != null)
            value = value.Substring(0, columnSize);
    } 
 }
```

Again, totally untested and written from scratch, but it might give you an idea how to get the column size. Of course this works only for `string`, but i assume that this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which column has the limit, and which field that column maps to, then simply truncate the field's value on all objects before calling Update():

```
myObject.StringField = myObject.StringField.Substring(0,25);
```